# Из-за чего возникла ошибка "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"?

Tags: nginx

Здравствуйте.

Контекст: работающий `nginx` сервер, на котором нужно поднять `ssl` на 443 порте.

Кусок добавляемого конфига:

```
server {    listen 443;    server_name example.ru;     root /path/to/root;    index index.php;    ssl                 on;    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.crt;    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.key;    ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;    ssl_protocols       SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;    error_log       /var/log/nginx/ssl.error.log;    access_log      /var/log/nginx/ssl.access.log; }
```

рестарт сервера... и вот:

при попытке перейти на `https://example.ru` отваливаемся с `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

восьмидесятый порт продолжает слушаться корректно, т.е. `http://example.ru` работает как надо

логи ssl.*.log девственно чисты

```
# netstate -nl | grep :443tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN # netstate -nl | grep :80tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

как я понимаю, оба порта слушаются как надо.

P.S. буквально вчера `ssl` корректно поднялся на аналогичном сервере с тем же куском конфига. (разница только в `server_name, root, ssl_certificate и ssl_certificate_key`)

Вопрос: из за чего может выстреливать `102 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по тому, что логи чисты то `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` возникает из-за того. что порт закрыт в `iptables` или другом `firewall`. Смотря что за дистрибутив. Если стоит `iptables`, то покажи вывод `iptables -L`.

Comment: Спасибо. Слона-то я и не приметил - https был закрыт в фаерволе.